# Trying to understand python csv .next()

Tags: python, csv, python-2.x

I have the following code that is part of a tutorial

```
import csv as csv
import numpy as np

csv_file_object = csv.reader(open("train.csv", 'rb'))
header = csv_file_object.next()

data = []
for row in csv_file_object:
    data.append(row)
data = np.array(data)
```

the code works as it is supposed to but it is not clear to me why calling `.next()` on the file with the variable `header` works. Isn't csv_file_object still the entire file? How does the program know to skip the header row when `for row in csv_file_object` is called since it doesn't appear the variable header is ever referenced once defined?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The header row is "skipped" as a result of calling `next()`. That's how iterators work.

When you loop over an iterator, its `next()` method is called each time. Each call advances the iterator. When the `for` loop starts, the iterator is already at the second row, and it goes from there on.

Here's [the documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#iterator.next) on the `next()` method ([here's another piece](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#generator.next)).

What's important is that `csv.reader` objects are iterators, just like file object returned by `open()`. You can iterate over them, but they don't contain all of the lines (or any of the lines) at any given moment.

Comment: so by declaring `header` I effectively call .next(). I just tested it and if I don't make 'csv_file_object.next()' a variable it still works. For some reason because it was written as a variable I couldn't see it. I think i got it now. Thanks!

Comment: @muchosalsa Yes, what matters is that the `next()` method is called.

Answer (score 6):

The `csv.reader` object is an iterator. An iterator is an object with a `next()` method that will return the next value available or raise `StopIteration` if no value is available. The `csv.reader` will returns value line by line.

The iterators objects are how python implements `for` loop. At the beginning of the loop, the `__iter__` object of the looped over object will be called. It must return an iterator. Then, the `next` method of that object will be called and the value stored in the loop variable until the `next` method raises `StopIteration` exception.

In your example, by adding a call to next before using the variable in the `for` loop construction, you are removing the first value from the stream of values returned by the iterator.

You can see the same effect with simpler iterators:

```
iterator = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5].__iter__()
value = iterator.next()
for v in iterator:
    print v,
1 2 3 4 5
print value
0
```

Answer (score 1):

csv.reader is an iterator. It reads a line from the csv every time that .next is called. Here's the documentation: http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html.  An iterator object can actually return values from a source that is too big to read all at once. using a for loop with an iterator effectively calls .next on each time through the loop.

Comment: thanks - @lev was just a little faster with the response. I had looked at the docs but it just wasn't clear to me until I removed the variable.

Comment: you should give the answer checkmark to the fastest response, but you should upvote all helpful responses.

Answer (score 1):

The csv.reader is an iterator. Calling .next() will obtain the next value as it iterates through the file.

In the below code the for loop is calling .next() on the iterator each time and allocating the result of next to the variable row.

```
for row in csv_file_object:
    data.append(row)
```

Answer (score 0):

The behavior of next() is more than that, all expose above is ok but there is one thing missing, also using next you are telling the iterator from what line you want to begin the iteration so is a problem let's say that I want some value that is in line 3 without going trough all the lines i can easily use next I got the value, but if I need to iterate on the first line in my case I can't because no matter what the iterator still starting at line 3 so I can not start from line 1 well there is a way but I didn't find it yet.

Answer (score 0):

Although the original question has been answered correctly in the accepted answer by @Lev among others,there is an error in the way `next()` is used in OP's code, which hasn't been pointed out in any of the answer.

> `header = csv_file_object.next()`

**Calling `next()` as a method on file object and assigning to a variable will lead to an error** as it does not return anything and just moves the iterator to next item(*next row in csv file*).
If you have to only skip the header, the following will do:

```
    csv_file_object.next()
```

To save header data in a variable, `next()` has to be called as a function with the file_obj as the argument.

```
    header = next(csv_file_object)
```

@Lev has linked to [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#iterator.__iter__) but missed pointing out this error in @davidheller's code.